# Convert java date to 18 dgit LDAP date

Tags: java, ldap

We have a requirment where we need to insert accountExpires date in Active directory. 
And AD only take input date as Large integer (18 digit LDAP date). 
I have a date in format `yyyy-MM-dd` (for ex : `2014-04-29`) and I want to convert this Java date into LDAP date 18 digit format i.e (`130432824000000000`).

Please let me know any work around to convert the below format and populate the AD with curre nt date format.

Comment: Do you use Joda Time or are you stuck with Java's date API?

Comment: `130432824000000000` is the number of ticks since Jan-02-1601. Since a Java `Date` uses January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT as its starting point, you will have to calculate the difference between the two.

Comment: Similar question but going the other direction: [Converting a ldap date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9806329/642706)

Answer (score 4):

I've spent a while on writing LDAP timestamp converter using java.time API
(Java 8).

Maybe this little tool will help someone like me (I've been here when I was looking for proper solution :)

```
import java.time.*;

public class LdapTimestampUtil {

    /**
     * Microsoft world exist since since Jan 1, 1601 UTC
     */
    public static final ZonedDateTime LDAP_MIN_DATE_TIME = ZonedDateTime.of(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    public static long instantToLdapTimestamp(Instant instant) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
        return zonedDateToLdapTimestamp(zonedDateTime);
    }

    public static long localDateToLdapTimestamp(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        return zonedDateToLdapTimestamp(zonedDateTime);
    }

    public static long zonedDateToLdapTimestamp(ZonedDateTime zonedDatetime) {
        Duration duration = Duration.between(LDAP_MIN_DATE_TIME, zonedDatetime);
        return millisecondsToLdapTimestamp(duration.toMillis());
    }

    /**
     * The LDAP timestamp is the number of 100-nanoseconds intervals since since Jan 1, 1601 UTC
     */
    private static long millisecondsToLdapTimestamp(long millis) {
        return millis * 1000 * 10;
    }

}
```

I've published full tool on GitHub:
https://github.com/PolishAirports/ldap-utils

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution using Joda Time, according to the definition found [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/ldap-timestamp.php):

> The timestamp is the number of 100-nanoseconds intervals (1 nanosecond = one billionth of a second) since Jan 1, 1601 UTC.

Sample code:

```
public final class Foo
{
    private static final DateTime LDAP_START_DATE
        = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        final Interval interval = new Interval(LDAP_START_DATE, now);
        System.out.println(interval.toDurationMillis() * 10000);
    }
}
```

Replace `now` in this code with your date and you should be set.

Answer (score 3):

this is JDK based solution

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    c.clear();
    c.set(2014, 3, 29);
    long t1 = c.getTimeInMillis();
    c.set(1601, 0, 1);
    long t2 = c.getTimeInMillis();
    long ldap = (t1 - t2) * 10000;
```

Comment: Are you sure about `* 10000`?

Comment: 1 ns = 1/1000000000 sec, 100 ns = 1/10000000 sec or 1/10000 ms

Comment: Shouldn't I get another instance of Calendar in the desired timezone to t2?

Comment: I mean, to "t1".

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me  :

```
static String parseLdapDate(String ldapDate) {

            long nanoseconds = Long.parseLong(ldapDate);   // nanoseconds since target time that you want to convert to java.util.Date

            long mills = (nanoseconds / 10000000);

            long unix = (((1970 - 1601) * 365) - 3 + Math.round((1970 - 1601) / 4)) * 86400L;

            long timeStamp = mills - unix;

            Date date = new Date(timeStamp * 1000L); // *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); // the format of your date
    //        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // give a timezone reference for formating (see comment at the bottom
            String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

            return  formattedDate;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest 4 lines code that worked for me:

```
public long dateTo18DigitLong(Date date){
    ZonedDateTime microsoftDate = ZonedDateTime.of(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"));  
    ZonedDateTime zonedDT = dateTime.atZone(date.toInstant(), zoneId.systemDefault());
    Duration duration = Duration.between(microsoftDate, zonedDT);   
    long longDate = duration.toMillis() * 1000 * 10; 
    return longDate;
     
    }
```