# LDAP TIME TO REQUIRED FORMAT

Tags: java, ldap

Currently I get `20150211152026.0Z` this format from ldap now I would like to store this in my database in this format `YYYY-MON-DD HH:mm:ss` with java.

Please guide how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806329/converting-a-ldap-date), you can do sthg like this;

```
String[] parts = inputDateTime.split("[.]");
String dateTimePart = parts[0];
String timeZonePart = "+0" + parts[1].substring(0, parts[1].length() - 1) + "00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssZ");
Date theDate = sdf.parse(dateTimePart + timeZonePart);
```

Thanks to [highlycaffeinated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3009/highlycaffeinated)

Updated version for your comment;

```
        String inputDateTime = "20150211152026.0Z";
        String[] parts = inputDateTime.split("[.]");
        String dateTimePart = parts[0];
        String timeZonePart = "+0" + parts[1].substring(0, parts[1].length() - 1) + "00";
        DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = originalFormat.parse(dateTimePart+timeZonePart);
        String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);  
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: I get the output as Wed Feb 11 16:20:26 CET 2015 and not what I need

Comment: I editted the answer, now output is 2015-02-11 10:50:26

Comment: But just another doubt what if I want an output in java.util.date and not string

Comment: I am not on pc but if you search string to date convention you Can find good solutions, i will also look for you.