# AD convert whenCreated attribute to Date

Tags: java, spring-ldap

I am connecting to AD using Spring Boot LDAP Starter. There is an attribute, `whenCreated` which stores the Date Time in Zulu format.

```
Input : 20111101000413.0Z
Output : 2011-11-01
```

I tried the below snippet but it doesn't work.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date cre = null;
try {
     cre = sdf.parse(createdAt);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mp.put("ldap_created_at", cre.toString() );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a ldap date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806329/converting-a-ldap-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried using the SimpleDateFormat *?

```
String createdAt = (String) attrs.get("whenCreated").get();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
//sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date cre = null;
try {
     cre = sdf.parse(createdAt);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
mp.put("ldap_created_at", sdf.format(cre) );
```

Comment: Yes , but am not getting desired output

Comment: cre.toString() will print the format based on the System  time zone