# how to convert date to 20160422060933.0Z format?

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, time, datetime-format

In angular I have to save data to database in this time format 20160422060933.0Z ?
Someone told me that this is Microsoft time format. I don't know how to convert date to this format, anyone encountered this before?
2016 is a year, 04 is a month, and 22 is a date but i don't know what 060933.0Z is. We use Dreamfactory API and SQL Server

Comment: I don't know who that *someone* is, but they were wrong. Go back to them and ask how you're supposed to put Angular datetime values into that format. (`060933.0Z` is the UTC time - Z is for ZULU, which used to mean GMT.) What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: The data is coming from Dreamfactory API so it might be Dreamfactory date format, and they want me to save new data using this 20160422060933.0Z format

Comment: Not seeing how to nicely convert this format to Date with js, but found similar question for java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806329/converting-a-ldap-date. I hope it helps you a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Later edit: based on another answer, actually this seems to be a standard format colloquially called a "LDAP date". See [Converting a ldap date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806329/converting-a-ldap-date) for some details on the format (and how to parse it in Java). It can for sure be easily parsed with any typical JS date library or even without any library.

Let's break it down into pieces.

- 2016 = full year
- 04 = month, padded to 2 digits
- 22 = day of month, likely also padded to 2 digits
- 06 = hour of day, padded to 2 digits, likely on a 24h scale
- 09 = minute of the hour, padded to 2 digits
- 33 = second of the minute, likely padded to 2 digits
- . = literal
- 0 = probably "second fraction"
- Z = offset from UTC. Z meaning UTC.

### Parsing it

You have several options to parse it:

1. If you assume you're going to always get an UTC datetime from the backend, you can naively parse it in JavaScript just by extracting the relevant substrings.

```js
const input = '20160422060933.0Z';
new Date(Date.UTC(
  input.substr(0, 4), // year
  input.substr(4, 2) - 1, // month is 0-indexed
  input.substr(6, 2), // day
  input.substr(8, 2), // hour
  input.substr(10, 2), // minute
  input.substr(12, 2), // second
  ("0." + input.split(/[.Z]/gi)[1]) * 1000 // ms
));
// Fri Apr 22 2016 09:09:33 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
```

2. You can be a little creative and actually manipulate the string into [an ISO format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). Then you can just use the native [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) function, which supports parsing ISO strings (other formats are browser-dependent). The advantage is that it'll support dates that are not UTC as well.

```js
new Date(Date.parse(
  input.substr(0, 4) + "-" + // year, followed by minus
  input.substr(4, 2) + "-" + // month, followed by minus
  input.substr(6, 2) + "T" + // day, followed by minus
  input.substr(8, 2) + ":" + // hour, followed by color
  input.substr(10, 2) + ":" + // minute, followed by color
  input.substr(12, 2) + // second
  input.substr(14) // the rest of the string, which would include the fraction and offset.
)) 
// Fri Apr 22 2016 09:09:33 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
```

3. Use a library like luxon, momentjs, etc. This you might already have a JS library in your project. You'd need to build a date format pattern to parse this format into a native Date object or some other library-specific object. For example, with [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) you'd do:

```js
moment("20160422060933.0Z", "YYYYMMDDHHmmss.SZ")
// Fri Apr 22 2016 09:09:33 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
```

### Formatting into it

This side of the operation is even simpler.

1. Without any date library, you just need to get rid of the "-", ":" and "T" separators from the ISO format. So you can just do the following:

```js
new Date().toISOString().replace(/[:T-]/g, "")
// '20230209175305.421Z'
```

2. If you want to use a date library, then you just do the reverse, format operation using the same pattern as for parsing. Eg. in momentjs:

```js
moment(new Date()).utc().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss.S[Z]")
// "20230209175222.5Z"
```

(note that I needed to place the "Z" in brackets due to https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/213).

Comment: Consider `let  [C,Y,M,D,H,m,s,c] = '20160422060933.0Z'.match(/\d\d|\d/g); return new Date(Date.UTC(C+Y, M-1,D,H,m,s,c+'00'))`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note to the other answer here:

You can use [ldap2date npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldap2date) for parsing, should be not that "heavy" as moment.

Code:

```js
import ldap2date from "ldap2date";
// or import { parse, toGeneralizedTime } from "ldap2date";

const dateString = "20160422060933.0Z";
const date = ldap2date.parse(dateString);
console.log(date.toUTCString());
// Fri, 22 Apr 2016 06:09:33 GMT

const str = ldap2date.toGeneralizedTime(date);
console.log(str);
// 20160422060933Z (note: no period.)

console.log(str.replace("Z", ".0Z"));
// 20160422060933.0Z

function getLdapString(date) {
  return ldap2date.toGeneralizedTime(date);
}

const d = new Date();
console.log(getLdapString(d), d.toISOString());
// 20230209181603.965Z 2023-02-09T18:16:03.965Z
```

And some monkey-patching to match "format":

```
function getLdapString(date) {
  return date.getMilliseconds() !== 0
    ? ldap2date.toGeneralizedTime(date)
    : ldap2date.toGeneralizedTime(date).replace("Z", ".0Z");
}

const d = new Date();
d.setMilliseconds(15);
const d1 = new Date();
d1.setMilliseconds(0);

console.log("Date with milliseconds: ", d.toUTCString(), getLdapString(d));
console.log("Date without milliseconds: ", d1.toUTCString(), getLdapString(d1));
// Date with milliseconds:  Thu, 09 Feb 2023 18:22:27 GMT 20230209182227.15Z
// Date without milliseconds:  Thu, 09 Feb 2023 18:22:27 GMT 20230209182227.0Z
```

Or to ignore milliseconds part completelly

```
function getLdapString(date) {
  const copy = new Date(date);
  copy.setMilliseconds(0);
  return ldap2date.toGeneralizedTime(copy).replace("Z", ".0Z");
}

console.log("Date with milliseconds: ", d.toUTCString(), getLdapString(d));
console.log("Date without milliseconds: ", d1.toUTCString(), getLdapString(d1));

// Date with milliseconds:  Thu, 09 Feb 2023 18:29:50 GMT 20230209182950.0Z
// Date without milliseconds:  Thu, 09 Feb 2023 18:29:50 GMT 20230209182950.0Z
```

Comment: can i do other way around with this library? i want to convert new dates to this "20160422060933.0Z" format?

Comment: @Sakén Yeah, but im not sure if you really should. Depends on your complete requirements, I added some examples with output, if you can provide some dataset to test - code can be tweaked.

Comment: @Sakén serban-petrescu's answer is also great, for my "dataset" with his  `new Date().toISOString().replace(/[:T-]/g, "")` code it will be:  
`Date with milliseconds2:  Thu, 09 Feb 2023 18:26:24 GMT 20230209182624.015Z` and `Date without milliseconds2:  Thu, 09 Feb 2023 18:26:24 GMT 20230209182624.000Z`